# Blue screen (BSOD) when Windows 7 hibernates or standby

Tags: windows-7, bsod, hibernate, standby, minidumps

Whenever I want to standby or hibernate Windows 7, It takes some times in blank monitor and gives a blue screen error and shuts down. Details below about Error message that Windows showed:

> Problem signature:
>     Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
>     OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
>     Locale ID:    1033
>
> Additional information about the problem:
>     BCCode:   9f
>     BCP1: 0000000000000003
>     BCP2: FFFFFA800744B060
>     BCP3: FFFFF800048D0748
>     BCP4: FFFFFA8008539460
>     OS Version:   6_1_7600
>     Service Pack: 0_0
>     Product:  256_1
>
> Files that help describe the problem:
>     C:\Windows\Minidump\090910-33961-01.dmp
>     C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-120869-0.sysdata.xml
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
>     C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

How do I repair that and what's the problem's origin?

Comment: I don't think it belongs here. Howerer, it's driver problem, try googling each hardware component you have.

Comment: excuse me for the mistaken place of my question. Do you mean I shouldn't ask this in the whole of stakoverflow? |  also I've several hardwares. it's hard to know which is the problem. What should I googling about them?   - Cheers

Comment: @1Geeky: ex: google WD10EARS windows 7 64bit BSOD hibernate

Comment: BSODs during hibernate or standby, or during resume from those, are almost always due to a bug in the power management code of a driver. Examination of the "minidump" file using WinDbg will usually tell you which driver was involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you out on different methods to troubleshoot BSOD issues:

> http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7hardware/thread/1d8560d1-5e4c-4a97-8f44-9545626d6837

Also, I read down the forum a little ways and found information about a hotfix that seems to match your symptoms.  Try that out and let us know how it goes.

> KB975599 - Stop error when you put a computer that is running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 to sleep, into hibernation, or when you restart the computer: "0x9F "

Go to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975599 and click on the link `View and request hotfix downloads`, select the platform (x64), and type in your email twice and type in the captcha ad click request hotfix.

Comment: Thanks a lot, My problem has been solved but I don't know whether by the hotfix you mentioned or by download and install service pack 1 on windows 7. Regards :)